# How can I combine color according to the picture?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I combine color according to the picture?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The combined cells would have the following formula:

For reference, I will use column B and the cells for part 1 are ranged rows 11 to 20, part b are 31 to 40, and combined are rows 51 to 60.

In cell B51, the following formula would be located for Red:

```
=IF(B11="",B31,B11)
```

Basically this will say: If B11 is empty, if thats the case, then return the content of B31 (the other cell). However, if its not, return its content instead, aka B11.

If both are empty, them empty will be returned.

Once entered, copy/paste the formula to the other 9 cells, and they will transpose automatically.